# Setting a time for how long it will take for a transition to finish

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm confused about how the transition property works.

Does transition time mean actual time?

For example:

```
.panel-left,
.panel-right {
 transition: all ease 30s;
]
```

You click on the play image and both sides open.

How come the 2 sides are open in less than 30 seconds?

Would I be using a different transition property to do that?

Would it be done a different way?

code https://jsfiddle.net/bfjcn4xk/

What would be the css property to use to set a time for how long it will take for the 2 sides to be fully open?

```js
(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
 
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".container");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacketa");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.curtain.slide {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 30s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100vw);
}


.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block !important;
}


.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
  transition: 5s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s ease;
}


.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.curtain.slide .split-wrap {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba(249, 6, 167, 0);
}


.container {
  height: auto;
}

.curtain.slide .j1 {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

.curtain.slide .j2 {
  transform: translateX(100vw);
}

.container {
  width: 990px;
  height: 1530px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #000000;
}

.container-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0 0 45px 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/jEMIULl.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="tcell">

      <div class="container hide">
        <div class="container-top">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-left"> </div>
      <div class="panel-right"> </div>

      <div class="split-wrap">
        <div class="j1">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="j2">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, transition time means actual time (as measured on your watch). But the panels are being translated much further than their actual width. I've put a suggested experiment/demo in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the two panels has width 50%. But to open them the CSS translates them by -100vw and 100vw respectively.

So, basically, they are moved further to the left and right than they need to be - they have disappeared from view before the transition time is up.

Try this experiment: change one of the panels translation to 100% - that means 100% of its width, not the container or the viewport's width. You will see that the right panel moves at about half the speed of the left one, it takes 30 seconds to get out of view.

```
.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);/* CHANGED */
}
```

I'm not sure why the code would have been written to translate in 100vw terms - 'normally' I would have translated an element its full (100%) width to get it out of view. Then it is very clear that the transition time is the time the element will take to disappear. So, either change your HTML to do as above, or reduce your transition time.